# How do I remove the empty space to right of website?

Tags: css

I'm working on a single page website with lots of floating divs all height:100%; - On smaller screens (like iPad) and in browsers like FIREFOX you can scroll horizontally to the side of the site and view empty space. This is driving me completely mad.

I have looked through other empty space questions but they're so specific that I can't see a correlation. I have nothing that would make the 100% body width break. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Test Site is available at http://test.mysteryskin.co.uk/

Might be useful to say that it is unfinished

Comment: You will see that you can scroll to the right, if not with cursor then with the arrow-right button on our keyboard

Comment: Happens on Chrome too...

Comment: The extra space disappears if you remove `width:100%` from `.contentbox`, `.infobox`, and `.aboutbox`, but it also messes up your the layout.

Comment: the site crashed my ff :(

Comment: On an IPAD it looks so bad as the empty-space on the right is always there, so the rest of the actual site pages are small.

Comment: @riskbreaker apologies. Chris, thanks, not sure what that means in terms of the layout but its must be to do with having nested DIV's that are 100%??

Comment: no problem i wanted to troubnleshoot it for you there but it just wont let me :(

Comment: are you able to check it on another browser?

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot this in firefox or chrome dev tools.  My suspicion is it has something to do with the image slider area.

Can you completely remove that area temporarily, and see if that fixes it on the live site???

Comment: @Michael I've done that but it hasn't altered the empty space.

Comment: @user826902 Can you take out everything but the first box, test that.  If it persists, take everything but the second box, test that.  If it persists still, then there is an underlying issue affecting everything.

Comment: @Michael Removing everything except the first div was fine but as soon as I added the first box element the empty space returns. After numerous searches i'm starting to think it has something to do with a min-width. But i've checked and its not the columns for the text or the background image. or the logo. ... any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue on FF by adding `position:fixed;` to the div with the class `trailer`. In fact I think the type of page you are trying to pull off will be better off if all of your non scrolling elements are fixed.

Not sure if that will help your iPad issue or not.

Comment: The trailer element is not an element that is non-scrolling, in fact adding this style to that class breaks the rest of the page and keeps the entire thing from being able to scroll.

Comment: @invertedSpear thanks for trying but that didn't work for me either. I managed to make it by using negative-margins and fixed px widths but its not accurately centered and it doesn't respond dynamically in the way that I need it to.